# Tomcat Context using Jersey conflict

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, localhost, jersey-1.0

I am using jersey to create a web server

my project directory has the following mapping

```
ProjectName 
     |.. src/main/java
       |.. folder1
         |.. restEndpoint1.java , restendpoint2.java etc
```

an example of how restEndpoint1.java looks is

```
@Path("/static1/static2")
public class DoStuff {

@POST
@Path("/static3")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces("application/xml")
public Response validation(String inputXML){
```

so an example of my url when deployed to tomcat is

```
 localhost:port/projectName/foldername/{restendpoint1.path}
```

my web.xml is

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>folder1</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/folder1/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Now I have to deploy this war as different contexts using the Context path in the tomcat web UI ( I am using Tomcat 7)

ie I would like the url's to be

```
http://localhost:port/{context1}/{restendpoint1.path}

http://localhost:port/{context2}/{restendpoint1.path}
```

I know that each context will have all the rest endpoints exposed to them but I dnt care about that , I just need to map it this way . The problem I am facing is

1) in the web.xml I need to give a folder name as the param so that becomes a root , but with this context requirement I cannot do it . Also I cannot map to each java class independently ( can I??)

2) In the tomcat UI how do I deploy my app using different contexts , I can only upload war or give the context and using a URL of the war on a server

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing the mapping in the web.xml

```
 <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/folder1/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

to

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```